# views content displaying on browser in Laravel 5

Tags: laravel, laravel-blade, laravel-routing, laravel-5

My file **authorsController.php** contains the following code:

```
<?php namespace App\Http\Controllers;

class authorsController extends HomeController {
    public function get_index() {
        return View::make('authors.index', array('name'=>'James'));
    }
}
```

My file **routes.php** contains:

```
Route::get('authors', array('uses'=>'authorsController@get_index'));
```

Lastly, my file **authors.index.blade.php** contains:

```
<?php echo $name; ?>
```

This is supposed to display 'James' on the browser, but instead displays error:

> Undefined variable: name

I also tried using `{{$name}}` instead of the echo statement to display the value of the variable `$name`, but the code `{{$name}}` is displayed on the browser instead of the value 'James'

Please, is there something I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Add `dd('test');` at the beginning of `get_index` method to make sure you really execute this controller

Comment: you need to put a back slash at `View` facade like `\View`

Comment: Hi Marcin, I did as you suggested, my controller page now looks like this: `public function get_index(){ dd('test'); return \View::make('authors.index', array('name'=>'James'));      }` but it's still the same, no difference

Answer (score 0):

```
authors.index.blade.php
```

Is this valid?  The faux dot notation in views is a directory. It's looking for /authors/index.blade.php not authors.index.blade.php. Update your view name to match and see if that fixes it.

```
return view('authors.index')->with(['name' => $name]);
```

This looks in the views/authors/ directory for index.blade.php, and will properly echo {{ $name }} because it's being run through Blade.

The directory structure is:
-/resources

- /views

  - /authors/

    - index.blade.php

Comment: My index page is actually in the authors folder in views, I think that is not the problem. I've also updated my authorsController page with the code you gave, it's still not working.

Comment: @user3554843 is the file located in /authors/ named index.blade.php or authors.index.blade.php? Also - your controller doesn't need to extend HomeController, it should probably just extend Controller.

Comment: The file is located in /authors/ and named index.blade.php. I've changed the code to extend Controller instead of HomeController. It's the same. Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

Laravel 5 uses {!! $name !!} Try that.